# php string two echo statements together

Tags: php, arrays, string, echo

this string is breaking my code and I am not sure why. If anyone can help me correct it I would appreciate it.

```
if ($p == $url) { echo '<li><a class="active" href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' 
. $label . '</a></li>'; } else { echo '<li><a href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' . $label . '</a></li>'; }
```

Comment: im sorry i edited it. that is not the problem

Comment: Add the warning/notice that you are getting. Code failing and code not working are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars(urlencode($url))` and `htmlspecialchars($label)`. The rest seems fine.

Comment: your saying add that line? where?

Comment: no, replace $url and $label with the corresponding part